One data and several setup exe installers in Inno Setup
Is there any way to prepare data as setup.bin and then create different installers for that bin file?
Data is huge.
I need to create an installer that plays a video on it and installer that lets the user choose some option and a simple installer that installs the data in one click.
The data is on the server, every user can select which type of setup he wants.
Then I need to re-compile the setup and give him his link to the setup.
If I want to re-compile the whole setup with the data for every user, it takes so long time and so space.

As Ken commented, you can pack your common files into separate [large] (sub)installer and run it from your user-specific [small] master installer.
See this question for details how run the child installer and how to display its progress in the master installer:

Make Inno Setup Installer report its installation progress status to master installer
(though in this question the child installer is embedded into the master one, what you do not want)



Another option is to pack your large common files into your own archive data file and extract it from the Inno Setup installer.
How to do that with progress display is shown here:

How to decompress archive file with progress and cancel button in Inno Setup


Yet another option is to modify the compiled installer with your user-specific data, for details, see:

Modify configuration file in compiled Inno Setup installer (custom configuration file for each downloaded executable)
Embed user-specific data into an authenticode signed installer on download

